# ¿Funcionamiento de una template en C++?

Tags: c++, template

Estoy en una ingeniería de computadores y este cuatrimestre tenemos una asignatura que se llama estructura de datos (la damos en C++).

Hace unas semanas nos presentaron la primera práctica sobre TADs y todo bastante sencillo hasta que en la práctica te pide implementar, de forma genérica, una matriz (es un programa que opera con matrices) con una template.

El caso es que el profesor se limitó a enseñarnos como utilizar la template, y cualquiera puede copiar el código.

No entiendo el funcionamiento de la template. He buscado en varias webs que lo explican pero ninguna de forma clara.

Cualquier link o respuesta me serviría de ayuda.

Comment: Las plantillas (template) son Tan, tan, TAN, t-a-n extensas que necesitaríamos varios hilos para hablar con detalle de esa característica de C++. En su lugar ¿por qué no compartes el código del profesor y las dudas que ese código te genera?

Comment: No era el código en sí, eran el concepto de template mi problema. Gracias por el aporte, han resuelto mi duda abajo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hablar de plantillas podría llevar a marcar un record como la respuesta más larga de StackOverflow, así que únicamente me limitaré a hacerte una sencilla introducción.

Las plantillas son objetos genéricos, es como un molde a partir del cual crear objetos con características particulares.

En el siguiente ejemplo creamos una clase con un miembro llamado `dato`:

```
template<class T>
struct Wrapper
{
  T dato;
};
```

¿De qué tipo es dato? así de primeras de ninguno. El tipo se determinará cuando vayamos a instanciar un elemento a partir de la plantilla:

```
int main()
{
  Wrapper<int> varInt; // dato sera de tipo int
  Wraper<std::string> varStr; // dato sera de tipo string

  varInt.dato = 5; // ok
  // varInt.dato = "abcd"; // ERROR, dato es de tipo int

  // varStr.dato = 5; // ERROR, dato es de tipo string
  varStr.dato = "abcd"; // ok

  std::cout << varInt.dato << ' ' << varStr.dato;
}
```

El ejemplo anterior, sin aplicar plantillas, quedaría así:

```
struct WrapperInt
{
  int dato;
};

struct WrapperStr
{
  std::string dato;
};

int main()
{
  WrapperInt varInt; // dato sera de tipo int
  WraperStr varStr; // dato sera de tipo string

  varInt.dato = 5; // ok
  // varInt.dato = "abcd"; // ERROR, dato es de tipo int

  // varStr.dato = 5; // ERROR, dato es de tipo string
  varStr.dato = "abcd"; // ok

  std::cout << varInt.dato << ' ' << varStr.dato;
}
```

Parece más o menos evidente que es preferible usar una plantilla que tener que repetir la misma implementación para tipos de datos distintos. Para el ejemplo que te he puesto la ventaja no sería demasiado grande, pero imagínate que implementas una lista de datos ¿Te agradaría saber que tienes que hacer 10 (o 20) versiones diferentes de la lista con el mismo código pero cambiando únicamente los tipos? (una para `int`, otra para `float`, otras tantas para estructuras que uses en tu aplicación...) Creo que me explico.

Las restricciones a la hora de indicar el tipo en una plantilla es que el código resultante debe ser compilable:

```
template<class T>
void Print(T dato)
{ std::cout << dato; }

struct MiStruct
{
  int id;
};

int main()
{
  Print(5); // ok, el operador << de std::cout tiene una sobrecarga para el tipo int

  MiStruct a;
  Print(a); // ERROR, no hay una sobrecarga del operador << valida
}
```

Así pues, a la hora de diseñar una plantilla es importante ser conscientes de que determinados elementos no son de un tipo concreto de datos. Este concepto cuesta entenderlo al principio y es necesario meterse en faena para llegar a entenderlo bien.

¿Y qué significa eso de `class T`?

`class T` se utiliza para indicar los tipos genéricos. Realmente `T` no es más que un identificador que le damos a uno de los tipos. Realmente puedes usar el identificador que te de la gana así que intenta que los nombres elegidos sean representativos:

```
// Esta funcion convierte una variable de tipo `Tipo1` en otra de tipo `Tipo2`
template<class Tipo1, class Tipo2>
Tipo1 Convertir(Tipo2 t)
{
  return static_cast<Tipo1>(t);
}

// Ejemplo de uso
char c = Convertir<char>(70); // Convierte de int a char
std::cout << c; // Imprime la letra F
```

Con esta información ya tienes más o menos lo suficiente para realizar lo que te piden. Yo atacaría el problema de la siguiente forma:

1. Crea una clase (no plantilla) que cumpla lo pedido en la práctica que trabaje con `int`.
2. Haz pruebas para verificar su correcto funcionamiento
3. Añade `template<class T>` o `template<typename T>` (es indiferente) a la clase y empieza a sustituir (donde proceda) `int` por `T`.
4. Las dudas que te vayan surgiendo las preguntas en SOes.

Comment: Creo que es una de las respuestas más claras que he visto en stack español. Con el ejemplo de template, y el mismo código sin template me ha venido la luz. Parece mentira que teniendo que pagar lo que pagamos por la Universidad no nos especifiquen estás dudas... Muchas gracias por tu tiempo y gracias por haberme aclarado mucho la idea de template.